# If Hemingway Wrote JavaScript, Fibonacci, Bolano

Tags: javascript

I'm working my way through Angus Croll's if Hemingway wrote Javascript, and in the Fibonacci chapter, when Croll presents the Roberto Bolano example for the sequence, I'm running into an issue that I can't seem to resolve.

I'm using GoormIDE and node.js to run my script.

I run the following:

```
//Bolano: A fragmented narrative
function LeonardoPisanoBigollo(l) {

if (l < 0) {
    return "I'd prefer not to respond. (Although several replies occur to me.)"
}

for (var i=2,r=[0,1].slice(0,l);i<l;r.push(r[i-1]+r[i-2]),i++)

//In the book, there's an unnecessary 'rationalTheorists' ARRAY here, but I left it out.

return r

}

console.log(LeonardoPisanoBigollo(5));
```

However, the output is always the truncated array,

[ 0, 1 ]

instead of the full array,

[ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3 ]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `return` in a `for` loop means that you only get a single iteration out of it. A `return` immediately terminates the function. I really don't know what this code is supposed to be doing, so I find it hard to suggest what a fix would be. As a guess, you might just need `;` after the `for()`

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for the suggestion, it worked. I wrote the code out of the book, so that's a typo on the authors part. The code outputs digits of the fibonacci sequence in an array.

Comment: You said there was a line you removed. This introduced a change in semantics - the `for` loop uses the next statement line as its body, if the body is not explicitly defined with `{}` of if there is no semicolon to eliminate the body. The line you removed was the body of the loop, by removing it, the `return` became the body of the loop.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks again. The above was an error on my part.